# Swift - Update Value of a specific item in a nested dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nested

I have a tableview and each cells are meant to be linked to an array inside a dictionary.

```
var buttonAction : [String: [ButtonAction]] = [:]
```

below is the struct of the buttonAction

```
struct ButtonAction: Codable {
var action: String
var array_linked_of_buttons: [[String:String]]

init(action: String, array_linked_of_buttons: [[String:String]]) {
 self.action = action
 self.array_linked_of_buttons = array_linked_of_buttons
   }  
}
```

It gets a bit complicated to explain the whole code but when I connect two buttons together, I can get the data for the variable "singleAction" which then can be added to the button action dictionary "array_linked_of_buttons".

```
let singleAction = [linkedButtonUUID: connectorMarker.UUIDpic.uuidString, linkedButtonCategory: "", linkedButtonName: connectorMarker.name]

                let mainMarkerAction = mainMarker.buttonAction["button actions array"]!

                    for existingMarker in mainMarkerAction {
                        actionArray.append(existingMarker)
                    }

                    var actionSub = actionArray[indexRowTag].array_linked_of_buttons
                    if let addAction = actionSub.filter({$0[linkedButtonUUID] == connectorMarker.UUIDpic.uuidString}).first {
                        print("MARKER Exists", addAction)
                    } else {
                        actionSub.append(singleAction)
                        print("UPDATED MARKER", actionSub)
                    }

                    let action = ButtonAction(action: actionArray[indexRowTag].action, array_linked_of_buttons: actionSub)


//ISSUE--?? mainMarker.buttonAction.updateValue(VALUE forKey: "button actions array")

                    saveData()
```

I can workout which item of the dictionary needs to be edited but how do I update that specific value? I am really confused has it just creates a new item but I want to update a previous one.

So for example, I want to append the "array_linked_buttons" of the item 0 and have 4 items instead of 3.

This is how my dictionary looks like if that helps too
[image]

I have searched other questioned but I still work it out.
Any help pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out i was updating the main dictionary array and not the nested array.
The code below is what I used in the end.

```
let singleAction = [linkedButtonUUID: connectorMarker.UUIDpic.uuidString, linkedButtonCategory: "", linkedButtonName: connectorMarker.name]

                var mainMarkerAction = mainMarker.buttonAction["button actions array"]!

                    for existingMarker in mainMarkerAction {
                        actionArray.append(existingMarker)
                    }

                    var actionSub = actionArray[indexRowTag].array_linked_of_buttons
                    if let addAction = actionSub.filter({$0[linkedButtonUUID] == connectorMarker.UUIDpic.uuidString}).first {
                        print("MARKER HERE", addAction)
                    } else {
                        actionArray[indexRowTag].array_linked_of_buttons.append(singleAction)
                    }

                    mainMarkerAction[indexRowTag] = actionArray[indexRowTag]
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying instead of changing value happened because you're using `struct` for `ButtonAction` which has value semantics and swift create copy on assigning to any variable.

You need to use `class` instead. Classes have reference semantics, so it won't create new instance on assigning to variable so you'll be able to update property of needed instance.

Comment: Thanks ilya, I changed it to a class but this didn't work. Any other ideas? Thanks